# I would like more specifics on how the Announcer badge is awarded

Tags: discussion, badges

When I post a link to a question or answer, and my user ID is part of the link, I know it is counted toward the Announcer badge when someone else clicks on it.

However, I have received the Announcer badge for a number of questions/answers that I know I didn't link specifically in any answer or comment in a way that included my user ID.

I do, however, add items and links to a list of "[Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419)" in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com, and when doing so, remove user IDs from the new item so that a copy-and-paste operation should yield an "anonymous" link.  Since I'm usually not directly responsible for any of the information in a linked item, it seems reasonable that I shouldn't try to take credit for it.  All the "answers" in this "often referenced" list are marked community wiki, even though my name may be listed at the bottom of the answer, so I thought that would add to the anonymity.

Are links posted as the result of someone else picking up one of these "often referenced" items nonetheless identified as associated with my ID, and contribute to the statistics for the Announcer badge?

Comment: Only partially related to the problem, but there is an easy way to find out if you shared the link outside the FAQ: go to the question for which you got the badge (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94414/) and have a look at the right sidebar. In the "linked" sections are all posts which somewhere have a link to this question. Going through these links you'll find that you mentioned it in a comment to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181031/compiling-multiple-tex-files-into-a-single-file?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks, @samcarter.  That works for most cases, but now I've found one for which I can't identify any possibilities, even the scenario I mentioned in the question.  I guess I'll just have to keep looking more carefully.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Can you share the one for which you can't identify any possibilities?

Comment: Well, it seems that was a false alarm; I found a link.  I'm still looking, but I have to do something else now, and will come back to this later.